# How can I get a returned value from a Thread in my scenario?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

So I'm wanting to parse a table on about 10 websites, so I want to create a new thread for each site. However, I'm not exactly sure how to return the data from this type of request.

Here's one class:

```
class TestRequest

  def initialize

  end

  def start
    urls = ['site1','site2','site3']
    existing_data = Data.pluck(:symbol, :page)
    data = GetData.pool(size: 10)

    urls.each do |url|
      data.async.perform_requests(url, existing_data)
    end
  end
end
```

and then GetData class looks like this:

```
require 'celluloid/current'

class GetData
  include Celluloid

  def perform_requests(url, existing_data)
    # perform HTTP request
    # parse HTTP response
    # return returned data ???
  end
end
```

What I'd ultimately like to do is have an instance variable in TestRequest class and simply add the returned value from GetData into that instance variable from the TestRequest class. After the threads are finished, I want to perform another action using the data in the instance variable.

I tried playing around with  `attr_reader`, but it doesn't seem to play in my favor.

I tried this:

```
class TestRequest

  def initialize

  end

  def start
    @returned_data = []
    urls = ['site1','site2','site3']
    existing_data = Data.pluck(:symbol, :page)
    data = GetData.pool(size: 10)

    urls.each do |url|
      data.async.perform_requests(url, existing_data)
    end
  end
  attr_reader :returned_data
end
```

and then

```
require 'celluloid/current'

class GetData
  include Celluloid

  def perform_requests(tr, existing_data)
        # perform HTTP request
        # parse HTTP response

        t = TestData.new
        t.returned_data << "value"
  end
end
```

but this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-threading and Ruby on Rails don't mix very well.

However, you should consider using the ActiveJob documentation (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html).

With ActiveJob, you can enqueue jobs and have them executed in the background. There are hooks method defined as well to notify you when a job is about to start, is running or have finished.

Comment: So I was using Sidekiq at first, but turns out eventually I just keep running out of memory, no matter how much memory I give my VM (tried giving it even 16GB and it still ran out of memory over time). Rather than leveraging sidekiq, I was just going to try using ruby's threading abilities. Perhaps that'd be a little bit more lower on the memory over time? Not sure.

Comment: I would love to use ActiveJob, but I'm not exactly sure how I could access one instance variable from all of the jobs, and add to it. Rather than trying to perform 100-1k queries every time the jobs go off (minutely), I'd like to just add them to a variable and use mass importing gems, but not sure if I can do that with ActiveJob since I'm not sure how to update/access an instance variable from each of the jobs.

Comment: I am not an expert in Rails ActiveJob stuff. I have more experience with similar technologies on other platforms.

Comment: However, the following link gives you an interesting intro:

    https://blog.codeship.com/how-to-use-rails-active-job/

You should consider a Job as inmutable.  Once it is created, it remains the same until its completion. The job itself can change its own instance variables during execution but not some other instance in your app.

Once completed, the information is passed back via a hook method.